# Is there a S3 plugin for Microsoft SQL Server backups in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backups

Is there a S3 plugin for AWS for Microsoft SQL Server backups? I have a use case that would benefit from this and am looking for the advise of the experts out there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming related question, since ask for external resources, plugins, books and tutorials this is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not provide any tools for MS-SQL backups. You need a third party tool like [AutomatiCloud](http://www.automaticloud.net) which offers a VSS-Agent for MS-SQL.